# Why doesnt this trignometric substituition work?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\frac 1 5\int\frac{x+1+5}{(x+1)^2+5}\,\mathrm dx$$

where i substitute $x+1 = \sqrt{5}\tan(\theta)$

After Substituition :

$$\frac15\int\frac{\sqrt5\tan(\theta)+5}{\tan^2(\theta)+1}\sqrt5\sec^2(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$$

but if i do $u = x +1$
and then further substitute and integrate i get :

$\int \frac u {(u^2 +5)} + \int \frac 5 {(u^2 +5)} $

which then gives :

$\frac {ln(x^2 + 2x +6)} 2 + \sqrt5 arctan(\frac {x+1}{\sqrt5}))$

not :

$ln(\frac{(x^2 + 2x + 6)} {\sqrt5}) + \sqrt5arctan(\frac {x + 1} {\sqrt5})$

Comment: i don;t know how to add symbols in markdown

Comment: Do you mean $\int\frac{x +1 +5}{(x+1)^{2}+5} $
and  $x+1 = \sqrt5\tan(\theta)$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for help with formulas.

Comment: Yes and Thank You!

Comment: Its my first time here

Comment: The substitution works perfectly.

Comment: No it doesn't when i substitute and integrate i get a $\sqrt(5)$ in the natural log part which when derived gives the wrong answer

Comment: It is best if you show your work, this way we can spot the mistake. The sub works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your trig substitution failing?

$\int \frac{(x+1)+5}{(x+1)^2 + 5} \ dx$

$x+1 = \sqrt 5 \tan \theta\\
dx = \sqrt 5 \sec^2 \theta$

$\int \frac{(\sqrt 5 \tan \theta +5)(\sqrt 5 \sec^2 \theta)}{5\sec^2 \theta} \ d\theta\\
\int \frac{\tan \theta}{\sqrt 5} + \sqrt 5 \ d\theta$

That looks relatively simple from here.

$\frac {\ln |\sec\theta|}{\sqrt 5} + \sqrt 5 \theta + C$

$\theta = \arctan \frac {x+1}{\sqrt 5}\\
\sec\theta = \sqrt {\frac {(x+1)^2}{5} + 1} = \sec\theta = \sqrt {\frac {x^2 + 2x + 6}{5}}\\
\ln\sqrt {\frac {x^2 + 2x + 6}{5}} = \frac 12 \ln (x^2 + 2x + 6) - \frac 12 \ln 5 $

The $\frac 12 \ln 5$ is a constant and can be added to $C.$

$\frac {\ln {x^2 + 2x + 6}}{2\sqrt 5} + \sqrt 5 \arctan \frac {x+1}{\sqrt 5} + C$

Answer (score 0):

As said by Doug, the substitution works. Before applying it, consider decomposing $$\frac{x+1+5}{(x+1)^2+5}=\frac12\frac{((x+1)^2+5)'}{(x+1)^2+5}+\frac{5}{(x+1)^2+5},$$ that makes life simpler.